# using matlab, check the existence of a continuous zero interval in all rows of a 2d matrix

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab, how can I find out if there is a continuous interval with specific length in which all elements of all rows in a 2d matrix are zero? I know I can do this using nested for loops, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the edits in my post?

Answer (score 0):

Here'e one approach with [`2D convolution`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) -

```
function out = continuous_zero_rows(a, n)

% a : 2D input array
% n : continuous length of zeros

out = any(all(conv2(double(a==0),ones(1,n))==n,1));
```

Sample runs -

```
>> a
a =
     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     2
     2     0     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
     2     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     2     0
>> continuous_zero_rows(a, 3)
ans =
     1
>> continuous_zero_rows(a, 4)
ans =
     0
>> a(2,4) = 0;
>> a
a =
     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     2
     2     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
     2     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     2     0
>> continuous_zero_rows(a, 4)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: 1D convolution on `~any(a, 1)` should be faster, right?

Comment: @beaker I am not sure how `~any(a,1)` is going to help or supposed to do here. I am looking for islands of `n` zeros along each row. So, how to incorporate `n` there, not sure about that.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for islands; I was looking for channels of complete columns of 0's.